# Convert char * to 4 character strings

Tags: c, string

I'm looking for a portable way to convert a string stored in a `char *` to an array where each 4 characters is stored in its own string.

To clarify, I want to be able to run a loop on every 4 characters in my string.

Example:

```
char *somebinary = "0001011000100010"
```

would be split so that:

```
somesplitbinary[0] == "0001"
somesplitbinary[1] == "0110"
somesplitbinary[2] == "0010"
somesplitbinary[3] == "0010"
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Sounds like you know what the problem you want to solve this. How have you decided to approach the problem, what code do you have written, and what is the specific issue you've run into?

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with

```
somesplitbinary[0][0] = somebinary[0];
somesplitbinary[0][1] = somebinary[1];
somesplitbinary[0][2] = somebinary[2];
somesplitbinary[0][3] = somebinary[3];
somesplitbinary[0][4] = 0;
somesplitbinary[1][0] = somebinary[4];
somesplitbinary[1][1] = somebinary[5];
somesplitbinary[1][2] = somebinary[6];
somesplitbinary[1][3] = somebinary[7];
somesplitbinary[1][4] = 0;
somesplitbinary[2][0] = somebinary[8];
somesplitbinary[2][1] = somebinary[9];
somesplitbinary[2][2] = somebinary[10];
somesplitbinary[2][3] = somebinary[11];
somesplitbinary[2][4] = 0;
somesplitbinary[3][0] = somebinary[12];
somesplitbinary[3][1] = somebinary[13];
somesplitbinary[3][2] = somebinary[14];
somesplitbinary[3][3] = somebinary[15];
somesplitbinary[3][4] = 0;
```

Comment: Why not a simple and elegant `memcpy()` instead?

Comment: @machine_1: surely you mean 4 simple and elegant `memcpy()` (and 4 initializations too?) ... OP now has another option :)

Answer (score 0):

buff - output buffer

str - string to be chunked

chunk - length of the chunk

chunks pointers to beginning of the chunks (if NULL - it is ignored)

```
    size_t split(char *buff, const char *str, size_t chunk, char **chunks)
    {
        size_t len = strlen(str);
        size_t chlen;
        size_t chinkc = 0;

        while(len)
        {
            chlen = len >= chunk ? chunk : len;
            memcpy(buff, str, chlen);
            if(chunks)
            {
                *chunks++ = buff;
            }
            chunkc++;
            buff += chlen;
            *buff++ = 0;
            str += chlen
            len -= chlen;
        }
        return chunkc;
    }
```